# Multiple INSERTs in One AQL Query: Access After Data-Modification Error

Tags: arangodb

**System Setup**

- ArangoDB: v3.4.7
- Java Driver: v5.0.0

**Problem**

I am trying to perform multiple inserts in a single query in ArangoDB. Specifically they are below:

```
INSERT { _key: @personId, firstName: @firstName, lastName: @lastName, gender: @gender, birthday: @birthday, birthday_day: @birthday_day, birthday_month: @birthday_month, creationDate: @creationDate, locationIP: @locationIP, browserUsed: @browserUsed, email:
@email, speaks: @speaks } INTO Person
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Place/@placeId } INTO isLocatedIn
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag0Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag1Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag2Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag3Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag4Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag5Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag6Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag7Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag8Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag9Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag10Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag11Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag12Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag13Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag14Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag15Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag16Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag17Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag18Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag19Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag20Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Tag/@tag21Id } INTO hasInterest
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Organisation/@studyOrg0Id, classYear: @classYear0 } INTO studyAt
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Organisation/@workOrg0Id, classYear: @workFrom0 } INTO workAt
 INSERT { _from: Person/@personId, _to: Organisation/@workOrg1Id, classYear: @workFrom1 } INTO workAt
```

With the following parameters:

```
Params: {personId=35184372096260, firstName=André, lastName=Atem, gender=female, birthday=501897600000, birthday_day=27, birthday_month=11, creationDate=1347546700674, locationIP=41.205.16.11, browserUsed=Internet Explorer, email=[Andre35184372096260@yahoo.com], speaks=
[en], placeId=1048, tag0Id=285, tag1Id=441, tag2Id=1761, tag3Id=2019, tag4Id=2800, tag5Id=2832, tag6Id=4994, tag7Id=5116, tag8Id=5446, tag9Id=5531, tag10Id=5677, tag11Id=6369, tag12Id=7340, tag13Id=7756, tag14Id=7853, tag15Id=8219, tag16Id=8481, tag17Id=9738, tag18Id=98
68, tag19Id=10410, tag20Id=11121, tag21Id=11211, studyOrg0Id=1980, classYear0=2004, workOrg0Id=205, workFrom0=2006, workOrg1Id=209, workFrom1=2005}
```

But when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 400, Error: 1579 - AQL: access after data-modification by collection 'Person' (while optimizing ast)
        at com.arangodb.internal.util.ResponseUtils.checkError(ResponseUtils.java:53)
        at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.checkError(VstCommunication.java:146)
        at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:128)
        at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunicationSync.execute(VstCommunicationSync.java:42)
        at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstCommunication.execute(VstCommunication.java:129)
        at com.arangodb.internal.velocystream.VstProtocol.execute(VstProtocol.java:47)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:71)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoExecutorSync.execute(ArangoExecutorSync.java:53)
        at com.arangodb.internal.ArangoDatabaseImpl.query(ArangoDatabaseImpl.java:197)
```

It seems like in ArangoDB I can't insert twice into the same collection in one query? Do I need to execute a separate query for each of these INSERTS?

Thanks for any help!

**Solution**

Rephrasing the AQL query using the `FOR` construct as follows solved the problem:

```
INSERT { _key: @personId, firstName: @firstName, lastName: @lastName, gender: @gender, birthday: @birthday, birthday_day: @birthday_day, birthday_month: @birthday_month, creationDate: @creationDate, locationIP: @locationIP, browserUsed: @browserUsed, email: @email, speaks: @speaks } INTO Person

LET hasInterestEdges = [
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/285"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/441"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/1761"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/2019"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/2800"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/2832"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/4994"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/5116"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/5446"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/5531"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/5677"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/6369"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/7340"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/7756"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/7853"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/8219"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/8481"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/9738"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/9868"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/10410"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/11121"}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Tag/11211"}]

FOR hasInterestEdge IN hasInterestEdges INSERT hasInterestEdge INTO hasInterest

LET studyAtEdges = [
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Organisation/1980", classYear: 2004}]

FOR studyAtEdge IN studyAtEdges INSERT studyAtEdge INTO studyAt

LET workAtEdges = [
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Organisation/205", workFrom: 2006}, 
    {_from: "Person/35184372096260", _to: "Organisation/209", workFrom: 2005}]

FOR workAtEdge IN workAtEdges INSERT workAtEdge INTO workAt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the java driver you can use the `collection.insertDocuments`
command and pass an array of documents to be inserted. See the doc [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/java-reference-collection-document-manipulation.html#arangocollectioninsertdocuments)

In the http interface you can use

```
POST /_api/document/{collection}
```

and pass a json with a document array as described [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/document-working-with-documents.html#create-document) (see create document section)

Finally, directly in AQL, you normally would use a `FOR doc in [arrayOfDocs] insert {<stuff>} into collection`

Here is a sample of inserting multiple records in AQL run directly in the web GUI:

```
let Params =[ {personId:35184372096260, firstName:'André', lastName:'Atem'}, {personId:35184372096261, firstName:'Robert', lastName:'Smith'} ]

for item in Params
insert item into test5
```

Comment: So you're saying that in AQL, back to back `INSERT` statements won't work, but if I can manage to express the same thing as a `FOR` loop, it will? Could you please include in your answer how to express the set of `INSERT` statements posted in the question using `FOR` as you've described?

Comment: I just added an AQL example. I used a shortened version of your param, but it should be good enough to show you how to set it up. Also I inserted the whole object, but you could project whatever columns you needed to insert.

Comment: OK I tested the proposed solution and it works, thank you! I find it quite strange, however, that a FOR construct gets around the "access after data-modification" error. Are we not still accessing collections after they have been modified? Some more explanation about why this works would be helpful.